# What is the recommended way to save chat history in Android?

Tags: android, caching, chat, asmack

I am programming a chat application using Asmack.

I am looking for the best way to save a chat history. Although I will do it server side later on, I still want some history (mostly recent) to be saved on the phone.

I read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

And I implemented the internal data storage to save the history. But is it the recommended way to save chat history/contacts?

Edit:

In reply to the comments; As follows, like I've done? (But adding the encryption)

```
String FILENAME = "contactName.History";
String string = "encrypted message history";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Will I have to encrypt the string manually, or does Android do it on its own?

Comment: You can save the data in encrypted format in text file, like WhatsApp does.

Comment: You can use file system to save your data.

Comment: Please check my question. I added what you said.

Comment: you can also save those data to sqlite database, which is faster to retrieve and easy to process.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use Sqlite data base because its easy to process it and also you can sort objects based on timestamp.

Comment: But when the user clears data from the spp settings the history will be gone isn't it?

Comment: Yes.. In that case you may want to store in cloud.